# How to add mime types to an htaccess file?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mime-types, add-type

I'm having an issue adding a mime type to my server. This is my current .htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile /usr/local/www/pass/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Mockups"

<LIMIT GET POST>
require valid-user
</LIMIT>
```

I want to add this:

```
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
```

But when I do, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I then reup the .htaccess file without the "AddType" line and it works fine again. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

in your virtualhost configuration and for the [directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in which the .htaccess file is located, to be able to use [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) directive.