# Google Chrome Not Rendering Font Properly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-font-api

I am making a website at the moment and I have noticed that my Chrome browser is not rendering Google Fonts properly. Does anybody have any ideas as to what this could be and how to sort it out please?

Please see the screenshot below for an example:

```
OS: Windows 8.1
Browser: Google Chrome 41.0.2272.76 m
Font: Open Sans and Bree Sans for headings
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP474.png

Comment: Check if you've specified `-webkit-font-smoothing`.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I have added:

`html { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }`

to my .css file and it has not made any difference.

Comment: Are you looking at the website through RDP?

Comment: No Jamie, I am developing locally.

Comment: In Developer Tools, are there any files not loading? e.g. WOFF/TTF ?

Comment: Jamie: No, everything is loading okay. (2 things are not, they are blocked by the Uni firewall because it's something on Google Maps it does not like. )

Comment: If you view Open Sans on [here](http://www.google.com/fonts/) is it the same or not?

Comment: No it is not, it's rendering fine. Could it then be a problem with my code?

Comment: @RossDoughty read this before using  -webkit-font-smoothing http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/

Comment: @RossDoughty Form where did you get font? I understand that you have it locally on your machine, and no font files are downloaded?  Do you use mac or win?

Comment: I would say a problem with code, or a problem with the fact it's running on localhost. For example I know IE has some stupid setting that tells all localhost websites to run in compatibility mode.

Comment: @Kinga He said he's using [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/).

Comment: @RossDoughty How does it look in IE and Firefox?

Comment: Seems to be working fine in both: http://i.imgur.com/VNXLxts.png

Comment: @JamieBarker oh sry i missed that. 

That kind of problems are almost always in the font. I had it with helvetica when i tried to use mac optimize version on windows.

Comment: @RossDoughty Do you know which font type it is using when it loads? TTF/WOFF/SVG? Maybe a MIME type needs setting up in IIS?

Comment: Here you go @JamieBarker - I think it is WOFF2 from the Network view in Developer Tools.

http://i.imgur.com/XUJ93Qb.png

(In Addition, it's loading Roboto for some reason.)

Comment: Try adding MIME type `application/font-woff2`

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to put that in... sorry @JamieBarker

Comment: @RossDoughty You're using IIS I assume?

Comment: No actually, I am using XAMPP.

Comment: @RossDoughty Never used it but AFAIK it's done in the .htaccess file. Adding the line `AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2`. You might also need [this info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365852/how-to-add-mime-types-to-an-htaccess-file)

Comment: I am afraid I do not have a .htaccess file. I will upload it to our server, look at it on Chrome on Windows on a different machine and see if it is replicated.